# There exists two triples of real numbers $(a,b,c)$ such that $a-\frac{1}{b},b-\frac{1}{c}, c-\frac{1}{a}$, are roots of a cubic equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, solution-verification, contest-math

There exists two triples of real numbers $(a,b,c)$ such that $a-\frac{1}{b},b-\frac{1}{c}, c-\frac{1}{a}$, are roots of a cubic equation $x^3-5x^2-15x+3$ listed in increasing order. Denote those $(a_{1},b_{1},c_{1})$ and $(a_{2},b_{2},c_{2})$. If $a_{1},b_{1},c_{1}$ and $a_{2},b_{2},c_{2}$ are roots to monic cubic polynomial $f$ and $g$. Find $f(0)^{3}+g(0)^{3}$.

WLOG assume $a_1>a_2, b_1>b_2 , c_1>c_2$

My approach so far.
From the given data, we can say that $$ (a_{1}+b_{1}+c_{1})-(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{b_1}+\frac{1}{c_1})=5 $$
We can also say

$$(a_1-\frac{1}{b_1})(b_1-\frac{1}{c_1})(c_1-\frac{1}{a_1})=-3$$
$$\implies a_1b_1c_1-\frac{1}{a_1b_1c_1}+(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{b_1}+\frac{1}{c_1})-(a_{1}+b_{1}+c_{1})=-3$$
$$\implies a_1b_1c_1-\frac{1}{a_1b_1c_1} = 2$$
$$\implies a_1b_1c_1=\frac{2 \pm \sqrt{8}}{2}$$
$$\implies a_1b_1c_1=1\pm\sqrt{2}$$

We know that $f(0)=-a_1b_1c_1$, and similarly for $g(0)=-a_2b_2c_2$, hence we get $f(0)^{3}+g(0)^{3}=-14$.

If I am wrong, please help me find my mistake. I don't know the source or the answer of the problem.Hence I can't cite the sources, thank you!

Comment: Products of roots should be positive $3$

Comment: How? Isn't the product of roots for a cubic polynomial going to be negative because it depends on $(-1)^n$?

Comment: you are correct

Comment: @Italian "*WLOG assume $\,a_1 \gt a_2,b_1 \gt b_2,c_1 \gt c_2\,$*" $\;-\;$ That assumption is neither justified, nor used anywhere. Other than that, the solution looks fine. One note is that you don't prove that the two triplets actually exist, just that *if* they exist *then* the end result holds true. But that's arguably what the problem expects you to assume once it says that "*there exists two triples...*".